# How to @import using chrome.tabs.insertCSS()?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, { code : '@import url("custom.css");' });
```

OR

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, { file : 'importer.css' });
```

**importer.css**:

```
@import url("custom.css");
a { color:red!important; } /* this rule applied successfully though. */
```

Doesn't seem to work as expected.

Why doesn't it work and how to make it work?

**Edit:**

Maybe I am looking at the wrong source code location, but the source code indicates that it uses the regular style sheet parser to parse the injected CSS. In other words, if the `@import` directive works in regular CSS documents, it should also work in injected CSS.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/extensions/renderer/script_injection.cc&q=script_injection.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=312-320

```
void ScriptInjection::InjectCss(blink::WebLocalFrame* frame) {
  std::vector<std::string> css_sources =
      injector_->GetCssSources(run_location_);
  for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = css_sources.begin();
       iter != css_sources.end();
       ++iter) {
    frame->document().insertStyleSheet(blink::WebString::fromUTF8(*iter));
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Sample code that's not working:

Directory structure:

```
ext.root
|-- custom.css
|-- custom.css.js
|-- importer.css
|-- manifest.json
```

**manifest.json**:

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "custom.css.js" ],
      "persistent": true
    },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "custom.css",
   "version": "1.0",
   "web_accessible_resources" : [ "*" ],
   "permissions" : [ "webNavigation", "http://*/", "https://*/" ]
}
```

**custom.css.js**:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(details) {

    console.log('inserting css');
    console.log(chrome.runtime.getURL("custom.css"));

    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId, { file : 'importer.css' });

    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId,  { code : '@import url("custom.css");' });
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId,  { code : '@import url(custom.css);' });

    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId,  { code : '@import url("' + chrome.runtime.getURL("custom.css") + '");' });
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId,  { code : '@import url(' + chrome.runtime.getURL("custom.css") + ');' });

    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId,  { code : '@import "custom.css";' });
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId,  { code : '@import custom.css;' });

    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId,  { code : '@import "' + chrome.runtime.getURL("custom.css") + '";' });
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(details.tabId,  { code : '@import ' + chrome.runtime.getURL("custom.css") + ';' });
});
```

**importer.css**:

```
@import "custom.css";
@import "chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/custom.css";

@import custom.css;
@import chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/custom.css;

@import url("custom.css");
@import url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/custom.css");

@import url(custom.css);
@import url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/custom.css);

body { background-color: red!important; } /* change page background color to red */
```

**custom.css** <sub>*(Rules in this file are supposed to be applied but not)*</sub>:

```
body { border: 20px solid red!important; } /* add a 20px border around the body. */
a { background-color: blue!important; } /* change all link's background color to blue. */
```

Comment: Is `custom.css` packaged with your extension?

Comment: It's not a _packed_ extension (ie: unpacked), but `custom.css` is in the same directory of `importer.css`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to inject such a file into a tab, relative URLs take its origin.
I.e. if you try to inject this into `http://example.com/test/index.html`, then the above CSS will try to load `http://example.com/test/custom.css`.

If `custom.css` is packed in the extension, you should use absolute path obtained from [`chrome.runtime.getURL()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL):

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(
  tabId, 
  { code : '@import url("' + chrome.runtime.getURL(custom.css) + '");' }
);
```

You may try to use the special constant [@@extension_id](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#overview-predefined):

```
@import url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/custom.css");
```

but I'm not 100% sure it'll work.

Lastly, make sure the imported CSS file is in [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: just tried all that you mentioned before you posted. Nothing worked. Btw, I don't see any network request in devTools to `http://example.com/test/custom.css`. Even tried hardcoding the output of `chrome.runtime.getURL()`.

Comment: This is what I put at the very beginning of `importer.css`: `@import "custom.css";
@import "css/custom.css";
@import "chrome-extension://gmhhjijghpdldhcaijiocceamdbfaklk/css/custom.css";

@import url("custom.css");
@import url("css/custom.css");
@import url("chrome-extension://gmhhjijghpdldhcaijiocceamdbfaklk/css/custom.css");
`

Comment: Is the file listed in `web_accessible_resources`? Can you make a tiny example extension and add a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

@important doesn't work with tabs.insertCSS(). insertCSS seem to be interpreted before injection in the page. How they are interpreted is not documented. For example !important do not works neither.